# Case insensitive condition in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, case, conditional-statements

I am using case in a bash script, but I was wondering what would be the regular expressions to match lower case or upper case words for the cases.

Ex:

```
case $name in
   JOHN)
     echo "hi" ;;
   JOE)
     echo "bye" ;;
   *)
     echo "nothing" ;;
esac
```

I want to match JOHN even if $name is equal to john.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
```

**Testing:**

```
s='john'
shopt -s nocasematch
[ "$s" == "JOHN" ]] && echo "matched" || echo "no match"
matched

shopt -u nocasematch
[ "$s" == "JOHN" ]] && echo "matched" || echo "no match"
no match
```

Answer (score 3):

Just convert `$name` to uppercase before testing, i.e.

```
case "${name^^}" in
```

or (if using a bash version older than 4)

```
case "$(tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' <<< "$name")" in
```